# Getiing number of columns in Pivottable with VBA after applying pivot filter

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have created a pivotchart programmatically from a pivot table My code creates three bars for each set of data fetched.  Each of the three bars needs to be formatted differently though the same for each set of data.

The problem is that I don't know how many sets of data there are and so I find myself unable to cycle through the seriescollection to set the points.

How do I get a count of the number of points in a seriescollection?

Thanks

Comment: Please share some of your code and/or a screenshot of your data.

Comment: You can use the `ColumnRange` property of the pivot table.  Just get the `Count` and subtract 1 if you have `GrandTotals`.